# I can't think of a word that means "one person can see something but the other people can't"

Tags: single-word-requests

So what I mean for example:
A man can see a ghost of a past person but other people can't. Sort of like a seer but i'm looking for a better word than that.

Comment: Do you mean concrete things or abstract?

Comment: *Clairvoyant*.... or perhaps *psychotic*?

Comment: *Charlatan, fraud, scam artist* all come to mind.

Comment: Nobody can see my [*point of view*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/point+of+view) but me.

Answer (score 2):

You could say he has [second sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_sight).

> Second sight is a form of extrasensory perception, the supposed power
>   to perceive things that are not present to the senses, whereby a
>   person perceives information, in the form of a vision, about future
>   events before they happen (precognition), or about things or events at
>   remote locations (remote viewing).

[Wikipedia]

Comment: Hi, Peter. Your answer was flagged as low quality and I think it's because the answer was too short. I edited your post and please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

omniscient, farsighted, and "before his time" could potentially all express meanings permitted by your usage.

Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find a word that avoids implying supernatural powers... Perhaps call that person a **"medium"**.  In your example, the man is ["one of the means or channels of general communication"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/medium) for seeing this ghost.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions I immediately thought of were "prescient" and "perceptive."

**Prescient** implies some foreknowledge of future events ...

> The ability to know what will or might happen in the future

... which, in a way, are things others cannot see.

**Perceptive** may be more suitable for someone who's simply more alert or tuned in to what's around them:

> Having or showing an ability to understand or notice something easily or quickly

I hope these are helpful!